# Intuition of & interpreting DCT

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, conv-neural-network, dct

I am trying to implement DCT of MNIST images in keras. I have a couple of questions with regards to the same:

1. When I try to visualize the DCT coefficients of MNIST dataset, I get to see see an image with black background and a pattern in white representing the frequency information of the input image. Why is the color inverted in the sense black background and white numbers as opposed to the original images having white background and black numbers?
2. If I take DCT of DCT coefficients of the input image, it gives me a stronger pattern (check the images attached) representing the original image, as compared to taking DCT just once. Why is that?

Here's my code:

```
import keras
from keras import backend as K
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten, Add
from keras.layers import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras.layers.core import Lambda
from keras.datasets import mnist
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
X_train = X_train.astype('float32')
X_test = X_test.astype('float32')
X_train /= 255
X_test /= 255

model = Sequential()
model.add(Lambda(lambda x: K.tf.spectral.dct(K.transpose(K.tf.spectral.dct(K.transpose(x), type=2, norm='ortho')), type=2, norm='ortho') ,input_shape=(28, 28,1), output_shape=(28,28,1)))
model.add(Lambda(lambda x: K.tf.spectral.dct(K.transpose(K.tf.spectral.dct(K.transpose(x), type=2, norm='ortho')), type=2, norm='ortho'),input_shape=(28, 28,1), output_shape=(28,28,1)))

X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], 28, 28, 1)

viz_dct = model.predict(X_train[:len(X_train)//2])

def get_reconstructed_image(coeff):
    coeff = coeff*255
    img = Image.fromarray(coeff)
    return img

print(viz_dct.shape)
viz_dct = viz_dct.reshape(viz_dct.shape[0],viz_dct.shape[1],viz_dct.shape[2])
plt.imshow(get_reconstructed_image(viz_dct[5]))
```

Below are the output images from the above program:

Original image:

[image: This is the original image from dataset]

After the 1st dct:

[image: This is the output of 1st dct shown as an image]

After the 2nd dct:

[image: Output after the 2nd dct]

Answer (score 0):

Typically, image values are 8 bits DCT output from 8 bits is 16 bits. Taking an image and doing a DCT on it then displaying it is likely to cause you to have pixel values that are out of range.